# Vue2 autocomplete component does not preserve input value

Tags: autocomplete, vuejs2

I'm new with Vue2 and I'm trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-autocomplete-js component and facing the problem:
after firing `:on-select` event, it clears out input's value and I can't find ways how to keep it.

My full example:

```
<autocomplete
    url="https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/"
    anchor="GeoObject.name"
    label="GeoObject.description"
    param="geocode"
    id="address_input"
    :custom-params="{ format: 'json' }"
    :process="processJSON"
    :classes="{ input: 'form-control'}"
    :on-select="fillAddressData"
    :debounce="500">
</autocomplete>

var vm = new Vue( {
    el: '#events-form',
    data: {
        processJSON: function ( json ) {
        return json.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember;
    },
    fillAddressData: function ( json ) {
        json.GeoObject.metaDataProperty.GeocoderMetaData.Address.Components.forEach( function ( el ) {
            if ( el.kind === "locality" ) {
                vm.city_text = el.name;
            }
        });

        vm.coord1 = json.GeoObject.Point.pos.split( " " )[ 0 ];
        vm.coord2 = json.GeoObject.Point.pos.split( " " )[ 1 ];
    },
    city_text: "",
    coord1: "",
    coord2: "",
    address_text: "",
    },
    components: {
        autocomplete: Vue2Autocomplete.default
    }
});
```

Help me please!

Comment: Do you mean when after making a selection from the autocomplete list, it does not populate the input field at all?

Comment: It erases it from the input. And I can't preserve it.

Comment: I use this same autocomplete and after I select from the list it populates the input with the new selection by default. I didn't have to do anything different. Only thing I can think of is your anchor/label needs to match what's coming from the api. How does your autocomplete result list look like?

Comment: Ready my question carefully please. I don't want to populate new selection to the input, I just want to keep in input what user just typed.

Comment: In my case I've forgot add `anchor` property to autocomplete - you should make sure that you put proper value in anchor in you scenario.